# Flask Authlib token revocation endpoint returns "invalid_client" error

Tags: flask, authlib

I'm trying to implement token revocation endpoint using `Flask` and `Authlib`, however it returns an error

```json
{
    "error": "invalid_client"
}
```

The controller itself

```py
@app.route('/revoke', methods=['POST'])
@require_oauth()
def revoke_token():
    revocation_response = server.create_endpoint_response(
        AccessTokenRevocationEndpoint.ENDPOINT_NAME, request)

    return revocation_response
```

Comment: Your code is not complete here. You need to also provide your authorization server implementation so people can help you.